# How to hide the console of a process given its PID?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, console, win32-process

I would like to start a process when I click on a button on my Qt application.
I created a process with `QProcess::startDetached(..., qint64 * pid)` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) but I have a console that I would like to hide.

How to hide it? Which function must I to use outside the process?

This code doesn't hide the console of my process (in win32):

```
if (AttachConsole((DWORD)m_PID))
{
    FreeConsole();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can recompile the program you are starting, you might make it a Windows rather than console program (in MSVC this is in the projects linker->system, settings, you want `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`).

Else the QT `start` method apparently never creates a console window, while `startDetached` does, so it might be possible for you to use `start` depending on your use.

Alternatively the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) flag for `CreateProcess` will prevent the automatic console, quote MSDN:

> The process is a console application that is being run without a console window. Therefore, the console handle for the application is not set.

Unfortunately it does not look like QT provides any way to create or use its `QProcess` with native flags or from a native handle (e.g. no `QProcess process(CreateProcess(...))`), allthough it was suggest some years back and rejected. [QProcess: Make it possible to set native process creating flags](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24619?focusedCommentId=259731&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-259731)

So you would either have to just use the Microsoft API's or find another library for multi-process work.

Comment: `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`  is an alternative to using `STARTUPINFO` to create a hidden console window. It creates a new console (i.e. instance of conhost.exe), and the process standard handles are set to the console input and screen buffers, and the console handle of the process references the new console, so console functions work normally. It's just that the console doesn't create a window, so `GetConsoleWindow` returns `NULL`. This flag is ignored with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and any function that uses the latter implicitly such as `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW`.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere directly?. The docs only state for "GUI processes" however, "For GUI processes, the first time` ShowWindow` is called, its `nCmdShow` parameter is ignored `wShowWindow` specifies the default value", but then since "For console processes, this information affects the console window if a new console is created for the process." id guess it is passed to the console host and is well defined, with that slightly different behaviour.

Comment: Using `STARTUPINFO` should always work if the child process creates a new console, i.e. if combined with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. The window is just hidden, so applications can get a handle to it and show it. The `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` approach implicitly creates a new console, and there's no window that can be shown ever. As to documentation, I don't know how meaningful that can be from writers that say something like "[t]herefore, the console handle for the application is not set", which is either false or very badly stated.